# deeplab Restoring from checkpoint failed when training on own dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to train a deeplab model on my own dataset (which is a subset of the ADE20k from which I extracted only a class of objects). I want to use the mobilenet as a backbone and start training from a pretrained model. Thus, I downloaded the pretrained weights from here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet (mobilenet_v2_1.4_224). Then I modified the data_segmentation.py to include my dataset:

```
_ADE20K_DOORS_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
    splits_to_sizes={
        'train': 3530,
        'val': 353,
    },
    num_classes=2,
    ignore_label = 255,
)

_DATASETS_INFORMATION = {
    'cityscapes': _CITYSCAPES_INFORMATION,
    'pascal_voc_seg': _PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION,
    'ade20k': _ADE20K_INFORMATION,
    'ade20k_doors': _ADE20K_DOORS_INFORMATION,
}
```

I modify the train.py file (changed value of the flags) as follows:

```
flags.DEFINE_boolean('initialize_last_layer', False,
                     'Initialize the last layer.')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('last_layers_contain_logits_only', True,
                     'Only consider logits as last layers or not.')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('fine_tune_batch_norm', False,
                     'Fine tune the batch norm parameters or not.')
```

I modify the train_utils.py file so as to exclude logits from the list of variables to be restored:

```
from deeplab.model import LOGITS_SCOPE_NAME
exclude_list = ['global_step', LOGITS_SCOPE_NAME, 'logits']
```

Now when I try to train I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint 
failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and 
the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the 
graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [576] rhs shape= 
[816]
[[Node: save/Assign_50 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class= 
["loc:@MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_11/expand/BatchNorm/beta"], 
use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"] 
(MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_11/expand/BatchNorm/beta, save/RestoreV2:50)]]
```

Clearly, there is a mismatch between the pretrained checkpoint and my model. What am I missing? Could you please help me out? Any bit of help is much appreciated.

In order to train I use the following command:

```
python deeplab/train.py --logtostderr --training_number_of_steps=30000 -- 
train_split="train" --model_variant="mobilenet_v2" --output_stride=16 -- 
decoder_output_stride=4 --train_crop_size=513 --train_crop_size=513 -- 
train_batch_size=1 --dataset="ade20k_doors" -- 
tf_initial_checkpoint=deeplab/mobilenet/mobilenet_v2_1.4_224.ckpt -- 
train_logdir=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/exp/train_on_train_set/train -- 
dataset_dir=deeplab/datasets/ADE20K/tfrecord
```

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the error by changing the pretrained weights. It worked with this model: mobilenetv2_coco_voc_trainval

Comment: Is that from the deeplab model zoo? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md  The download link being http://download.tensorflow.org/models/deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_trainval_2018_01_29.tar.gz ? I tried this but am still getting the same error. I am using identical options to you except for `--dataset="cityscapes"` because my training images come from cityscapes.

Comment: Never mind, my `PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR` folder still had checkpoints in it from my last failed training attempt. TF was trying to restart training from those checkpoints, and realising that they didn't match the initial checkpoint... Training is running now. I'll just have to wait and see if it converges to a useful result!